# Raw use of parameterized class. Lombok vs SuperBuilder

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I have problem with warning sonar, when try used mapstruct

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'CompanyInformationDto.CompanyInformationDtoBuilder'
```

and

```
Unchecked call to 'company(List<Companies>)' as a member of raw type 'com.project.domain.model.company.CompanyInformationData.CompanyInformationDataBuilder'
```

my classes:

```
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class CompanyInformationDto extends CompanyInformationData {
}

@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@ToString
public class CompanyInformationData {
    ..
}
```

mapper:

```
@AfterMapping
default void afterMapping(@MappingTarget CompanyInformationDto.CompanyInformationDtoBuilder  source) { // Raw use of parameterized class 'CompanyInformationDto.CompanyInformationDtoBuilder' 

   List<Companies> companies = new ArrayList<>();
            ....
   source.company(companies).build(); //Unchecked call to 'company(List<Companies>)' as a member of raw type 'com.project.domain.model.company.CompanyInformationData.CompanyInformationDataBuilder'
}
```

Pls help, how resolve this problem?

Comment: How about `CompanyInformationDto.CompanyInformationDtoBuilder<?, ?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SuperBuilder` generates a builder class with 2 type parameters (in addition to whatever type parameters your class already has). The first type parameter is the class the builder will produce, and the second type parameter is the builder's type.

These type parameters aren't that relevant when you are taking a builder as a parameter. You can just use the `?` wildcard to "ignore" them. Change the type of the `source` parameter to:

```
CompanyInformationDto.CompanyInformationDtoBuilder<?, ?>
```

This is also the return type of the `builder` static method in `CompanyInformationDto`.

---

Lombok needs these type parameters so that things like this doesn't happen:

```
Subclass.builder()
    .someSuperclassField(foo) // this returns a builder of the superclass!
    .someSubclassField(bar) // oops, there is no someSubclassField in the superclass builder!
```